# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/api/auth/produits/files' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i want to save a file(image) to my serve spring but this i have this problem

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {FileUploader} from 'ng2-file-upload'; @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl
 ./app.component.html','
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']  
 })
 export class 
 here AppComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput: ElementRef; 
 uploader: FileUploader;
 isDropOver: boolean; ngOnInit(): void {
 const headers = 
 [{name: 'Accept', value: 'application/json'}];
 this.uploader = new FileUploader({url: 
 'http://localhost:9090/api/auth/produits/files', autoUpload: true, 
  headers: headers});
  this.uploader.onCompleteAll = () => alert('File uploaded');
  }
  fileOverAnother(e: any): 
  void {
  this.isDropOver = e;
  }
  fileClicked() {
  this.fileInput.nativeElement.click();
  }
  }  


@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@PostMapping(value = "/produits/files")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
throws IOException {
    fileService.storeFile(file);
}
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
>       'http://localhost:9090/api/auth/produits/files' from origin 
>       'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to 
>       preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 
>       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the 
>       wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The 
>       credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>       controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
>    i dont know what is the probleme with this code. help me please?

Comment: How about the allowed headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the allowed headers options is not defined:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders={"Accept"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@PostMapping(value = "/produits/files")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
throws IOException {
    fileService.storeFile(file);
}
```

When specifying crossorigin, you can customize it by specifying the following annotations: origins, methods, allowedHeaders, exposedHeaders, allowCredentials or maxAge

Comment: thank you but even with this i have the same problem

Comment: i also add allowCredentials  and it work thank you so much

Comment: @S'iwarHadjAli, glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing the CORS Error**

There are 2 ways to do so:-

1. if you own the backend server, it would be best to configure the
   backend server to return the appropriate CORS HTTP headers Configure
2. Angular CLI Proxy which is our focus in this article.

**Angular CLI proxy**

Here, I am assuming you have an angular project with some services making HTTP requests.
Create the Proxy Configuration File called proxy.conf.json in the root of the src folder

```
                "/api": {
                    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
                    "secure": false
                }
            }
```

2. Configure angular.json with proxyConfig key under the architect>serve>options that point to the src/proxy.conf.json as below

> 

```
           "architect": {
                "serve": {
                  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                  "options": {
                    "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
                    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
                  },
```

**Now, simply run ng serve and you are done.**